# Custom video controls using UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, avplayer

I'm creating custom video controls for AVPlayer. Goal is to make them look like those sliders when changing things like contrast in Camera app.

[what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsOV9.png)

This is what I have currently. It's a UIScrollView with pattern image in background. It's working, it's moving with a video progress, I can rewind video etc. But it starts on left side of master view, and I need it to start from that red line. So for example for video with currentTime = 8s it should look like that: [what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0wgx.jpg)

For 0 there should be no gray lines on the left of red one.

It looks like I need some form of negative offset on that UIScrollView but afaik it's not possible. What is the easiest way to achieve such effect?